# javascript object reference not working by getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

When i change

```
$('#textarea').textcomplete([{

    //irrelevant code here

}]);
```

to

```
textarea.textcomplete([{

     //irrelevant code here
}]);
```

,it doesnt work. am i doing something wrong here?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tnzj2nfu/4/

I am using [jquery.textcomplete.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/0.2.2/jquery.textcomplete.min.js) plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `textarea` is a dom element reference, and the `textcomplete` is a jQuery plugin which can be invoked using a jQuery object reference only.

Also there is no need to use `getElementById()` if you have jQuery, you can just use the id selector to get the element reference.

If you have a dom element reference, you can pass that to jQuery to get a jQuery reference

```
$(textarea).textcomplete([{...})
```